# How to redirect a name-based VirtualHost to a different port?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, endpoint

I have a virtuoso sparql endpoint installed, which I want to make available through a hostname (e.g. www.virtuosoexample.com). The thing with virtuoso is that the is no Document root. The endpoint is initiated by the daemon and made available through a source port (e.g. localhost:1234/)

I know how to set a virtual host pointing to a document root, but i don't know how to do this for a server with a port number.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Below is the code, how I would do it with a document root.

I tried to change that (naively) into localhost:1234/sparql, but that didn't work

> <VirtualHost *>
>
> ```
>    ServerName www.virtuosoexample.com <www.virtuosoexample.com> 
>     ServerAlias www.virtuosoexample.com <www.virtuosoexample.com> 
>
>     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.wp-sparql.log
>
>     # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
>     # alert, emerg.
>     LogLevel warn
>
>     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.wp-sparql.log combined
>
>
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/endpoint/sparql/
>     <Directory /var/www/endpoint/sparql>
>             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>             AllowOverride All
>             Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>     </Directory>
> ```
>
> </VirtualHost>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not do this by mucking with Apache's DocumentRoot.  Instead, you would use `mod_proxy` and set up Apache as a reverse proxy.

You would add something like:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:1234/sparql
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1234/sparql
```

to your configuration.  Make sure mod_proxy is loaded by Apache.

Here is the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use mod_proxy for this. For example:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.virtuosoexample.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:1234/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1234/
</VirtualHost>
```

See the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more details.

Note that if you want `http://www.virtuosoexample.com/` to be proxied to `http://localhost:1234/sparql`, that you may encounter some problems if the links returned by virtuoso are not relative links. If so, you may consider using [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) or [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html)